# Result lost with Extjs grid panel "next button"

Tags: button, extjs, grid

I have a grid panel which works with a search function. Each time the search button is pressed, a query is passed and the grid panel is sorted and display

The query works fine. But when I pressed the "Next Page Button" The query information got lost and returns to the original states [with no query execution]

```
bbar: new Ext.PagingToolbar(
{
    store: store,
    pageSize: 20,
    plugins: [new Ext.ux.Andrie.pPageSize()],
    displayInfo: true,
    width: '400',
    refresh: function(pt, o) {
        store.reload();
        FormPanel.findById('grid').getView().refresh();
    },
    emptyMsg: "No message to display"
    }
)
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

are you using a server side script (ex. PHP )? in fetching the data that you are displaying in the grid..? I haven't tried using the lastOption thing but you could try this..its only a simple PHP trick... using `$_SESSION`... I also have the same situation like you..and the $_SESSION function works for me.

Here's the sample code.

Normally in server side, you have a code like this to fetch some data in the database.
You need to POST the parameters you send from search field. You did not post here your server side code. So I would assume that it would look like this.

//first thing you need to post the parameters from the search filed to be search in the database//

```
$pattern = $_REQUEST['search_pattern']; //you may also use the $_POST instead of $_REQUEST
```

// your database query may look like this..

```
("SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE table_data LIKE %$pattern% ");
```

//every time you load your grid. It will always call the server.so if you put a condition that data to be displayed will depends on the value of your search field, if your `$_POST` function return a NULL definitely it will not show any data.

So if you put a value in the search field and load the grid. At first load the server got a value for the pattern so you got your output on the grid but remember that the server side pages holds the value one time only, if the server side page got refreshed or load again the value will now be null unless you again put something on the search field. That's what I think the reason why your not getting display after you pressed the next button because the next button loads again the server side pages but this time the next button has no parameters that's why the server cant get any data because the pattern is now NULL. So in order to hold the value that you enter previously for a long time we need to use the $_SESSION...// the code would look like this one.

Since every time we load the server page it always do the $_POST function,so if the we post a null value therefore it would result a null also.to get the value that we've posted a while ago form the search field we will put the value to the session. Here its goes...

```
$pattern = $_POST['search_pattern'];
```

At first if you type something on the search field, the $pattern will have a value,then we will save that to a session variable,

```
$_SESSION['pattern'] = $pattern;
```

But remember that the next button also loads the server side pages every time you pressed the next it reloads the server page and at this time the `$_POST` returns a null value, because we didn't send a parameters along with the next button. So we need to store only a value on the session variable ones the POST has a value and it is when you type a word on the search field. We need to do like this.

```
$pattern = $_POST['search_pattern'];

if($pattern != ''){ 
// we need to check if the value is null because when you pressed the next button after it reloads the pages it would now be null and this time we need to get the previous value. while if the  value is not null we will save it to the session variable..

$_SESSION['pattern'] = $pattern;

}else{

    // here is when the next button is pressed it will go here since the $_POST is now null
    we will get the previous value that we saved on the session variable//


$pattern = $_SESSION['$pattern'];

}
```

then after that,query the data to the database...

the whole code would look like this..

```
<?php
session_start();

// mysql connection here//

$pattern = $_POST['search_pattern'];

if($search_pattern !=''){

$_SESSION['pattern'] = $pattern;

}else{

$pattern = $_SESSION['pattern'];

}

$start = ($_REQUEST['start'] != '') ? $_REQUEST['start'] : 0;
$limit = ($_REQUEST['limit'] != '') ? $_REQUEST['limit'] : 20;

$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM students WHERE lname LIKE '$pattern%' ");

$totaldata = mysql_num_rows($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$items[] = array(
        'id' => $row['student_id'],
    'lname' => $row['lname'],
    'fname' => $row['fname'],
    'mname' => $row['mname'],
    'gender' => $row['gender'],
);


}

  $matches = Array();
  foreach ($items as $item) {
      $matches[] = $item;
    }

echo '({"totalCount":"'.$totaldata.'","matches":'.json_encode($matches).'})'; 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which store your are using. but reload requires options argurments as,

Reloads the Record cache from the configured Proxy using the configured Reader and the options from the last load operation performed.

Parameters:
options : Object
(optional) An Object containing loading options which may override the options used in the last load operation. See load for details (defaults to null, in which case the lastOptions are used).

To add new params to the existing params:

```
lastOptions = myStore.lastOptions;
Ext.apply(lastOptions.params, {
    myNewParam: true
});
myStore.reload(lastOptions);
```

Returns:
void

refer: http://extjs.cachefly.net/ext-3.4.0/docs/